# How to execute multi query from list at once time in Python?

Tags: python, postgresql, tornado

I'm using Tornado and Postgres, I have some queries (4 or 5) that I appended  to the list during program and now I want to execute all of them at once time!

when I tried to execute I got error that was:

```
"DummyFuture does not support blocking for results"
```

I executed this code:

```
 yield self.db.execute(''.join(queries)).result()
```

"queries" is list of queries!

This is my connection pool and also Tonado setting:

```
ioloop = IOLoop.instance()

application.db = momoko.Pool(
    dsn='dbname=xxx user=xxx password=xxxx host=x port=xxxx'
    size=xx,
    ioloop=ioloop,
)

# this is a one way to run ioloop in sync
future = application.db.connect()
ioloop.add_future(future, lambda f: ioloop.stop())
ioloop.start()
future.result()  # raises exception on connection error

http_server = HTTPServer(application)
http_server.listen(8888, 'localhost')
ioloop.start()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't call `result()` on a Future in a Tornado coroutine. Get results like this:

```
@gen.coroutine
def method(self):
    result = yield self.db.execute('...')
```

Also, I don't think it will work to just join your queries as strings. The outcome won't be valid SQL. Instead:

```
@gen.coroutine
def method(self):
    results = yield [self.db.execute(q) for q in queries]
```

Comment: Thanks, by the way instead of  "yield self.db.execute(''.join(queries)).result() " I executed "yield queries", I append my queries to my list as you explained like "append(self.db.execute(....)